# .Net bundler strips whitespace when it encounters a plus sign?

Tags: css, .net, bundle, bundling-and-minification

Given a simple CSS definition like this:

`min-width: calc(50% + 12px);`

When the CSS is minified/bundled, the bundler seems to strip out certain white space so that the above looks like this:

`min-width: calc(50%+ 12px);`

which, of course, is invalid CSS and is ignored by the browser. Does anyone know how/why this happens, and if there is some sort of setting/fix to ameliorate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.banner {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(40px);
  min-width: calc(50% + 12px);
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">This is a banner!</div>
```